# Adding Hyperlink to Datalist with only CSS3+HTML5

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, autocomplete, datalist

I want to add hyperlinks to a datalist so that when the user selects one of the items in the datalist it will take them to an HTML page? I'm looking for the simplest solution possible. Is there a way to do this with just CSS3+HTML5? jQuery would be an option for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" name="srch" id="srch" list="datalist1">
<datalist id="datalist1">
  <option value="Canada">
  <option value="China">
  <option value="Mexico">
  <option value="United Kingdom">
  <option value="United States of America">
  <option value="Uruguay">
</datalist>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should consider that this HTML control is not supported in all browsers, and for your desired use I would recommend to use an autocomplete plugin, you need to use Javascript

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with without javascript, but it is easy to do especially with jquery. Here'a a little example of how it could work:

```
$('#srch').on('input', function(){
  var page = $(this).val();
  window.location.href = 'your url' + page;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation page. I guess my jQuery is pretty limited. So if I wanted each option to go to a different html page would the code look like this...?
$('#srch').on('input', function(){
  var page = $(Canada).val();
  window.location.href = 'canada.html' + page;
});